# Eloqua bulk REST API gives serialization error

Tags: rest, eloqua-bulk-api

I am trying to make bulk REST API call to import data to Eloqua. I am able to make call to GET, But POST gives me "400- There was a Serialization Error".

This is first step to get response for creating import definition from Eloqua Bulk REST.

```
URL: /api/bulk/2.0/contacts/imports

Headers:
Authorization: valid oAuth2 token
Content-Type: application/json
```

Body:

```
{  
   "name": "AppSource Test",
   "fields": {  
      "firstName": "{{Contact.Field(C_FirstName)}}",
      "lastName": "{{Contact.Field(C_LastName)}}",
      "emailAddress": "{{Contact.Field(C_EmailAddress)}}"
   },
   "identifierFieldName": "emailAddress"
}
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/BulkAPI/Tutorials/Import.htm%3FTocPath%3DBulk%25202.0%2520API%7CTutorials%7C_____2) also doesn't have details about this.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

[Change Body content type to "raw"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nds2.png)

Explanation:
Eloqua expects the data it receives be in "raw" format. Although Header says Content type json, Setting Body as "raw" works.